# How to write C# query to check the attributes of the XML

Tags: c#, xml

/*How to write the C# query to check the attributes of the XML listed below and the      string inside the element of XML  "Icolumn" that is "RIA:RIB:RIC:RID:RIE:RIF##0-15". Actually, I need to read the letters A,B,C,D,E,F append with RI and column 0-15.*/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--.......... Downlink DL ....................................-->
<Panel>
<DL IRows = "1" >
<DL Columns="1">
<Icolumn> RIA:RIB:RIC:RID:RIE:RIF##0-15 </Icolumn>
</DL>
</DL>

<DL IRows = "1" >
<DL Columns="2">
<Icolumn> RIA:RIB:RIC:RID:RIE:RIF##0-15 </Icolumn>
</DL>
</DL>

<DL IRows = "1" >
<DL Columns="3">
<Icolumn> RIA:RIB:RIC:RID:RIE:RIF##0-15 </Icolumn>
</DL></DL>

<DL IRows = "1" >
<DL Columns="4">
<Icolumn> RIA:RIB:RIC:RID:RIE:RIF##0-15 </Icolumn>
</DL>
</DL>
```

Comment: In case you have not tried it here is an example of [LINQ to XML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24376/LINQ-to-XML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query to get the attributes of `DL` nodes and values of `Icolumn` nodes.

```
var doc = XElement.Load(@"path to your xml");
var result = doc.Nodes()
    .Cast<XElement>()
    .Select(n=>
    {
        var columnsDlElement = n.FirstNode as XElement;
        var iColumnElement = columnsDlElement.FirstNode as XElement;
        return new
        {
            Rows = Convert.ToInt32(n.Attribute("IRows").Value),
            Columns = Convert.ToInt32(columnsDlElement.Attribute("Columns").Value),
            IColumn = iColumnElement.Value
         };
     });
```

However, I did not undestand exactly what do you want to do with the values of `Icolumn` elements so I can't provide any code here.

Comment: I am new in C# and having problem to execute your code as it is not executing the loop "result" :(. Can you help me more?

Thank you Repierre. Actually in the Icolumn, I need to extract the string and parse/split the string to read my GRID rows A,B,C,D,E and F and its column 0-15. Hope now you can understand.

Comment: @Kash, use `result` in a `foreach` loop like this: `foreach(var item in result){/* do something*/}`. Please provide an example of the desired output and I'll edit my answer to give you the code.

Comment: kindly find attached the detailed explanation of application which I am trying to build on this link 
http://www.2shared.com/photo/x_MedZIW/explanation_stackflow.html

CarlosJ: Good tutorial especially for the beginners like me :)

Comment: @Kash, I'm sorry, I still don't understand. Please provide an examle like this: _Given the value `RIA:RIB:RIC:RID:RIE:RIF##0-15` of the element `Icolumn` I want to break this value into `RIA`, `RIB` etc_. What is your desired output? Also a chat would be nice :)

Comment: RIA, RIB... are the grid rows which you can see the label written on the left side of the panel 1. I want to extract the value from panel 1 to panel 2 when I press the button as shown in the snap. 
My desire output is the panel 2 grids :)
I can't chat on stackflow as my reputation is too low due to my basic qns on this forum but thank to you guys ;). My ID is syedkashanali@gmail.com. If u would like to chat me on gmail then I will be very thankful to you. Or send me ur ID, I will email u in detain what the output requirement.